# Not able to alter the Database table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add one more column to the existing table. But the table is not getting altered. Here is the code

```
<?php

$host_name = 'localhost';
$user_name = 'root';
$password  = '';
$database = "test";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host_name,$user_name,$password);
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);


$add = mysqli_query($connection,"ALTER TABLE employee add PH.NO INT(10)");
if ($add) {
    echo "Table Altered<strong>";
    # code...
}
else {
    echo "Table not altered";
}

?>
```

Comment: `echo "Table not altered";` => http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and get the *real* error ;-) while developing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a `.` in the column name. So try replacing it with `_` and make sure you put all the column names within backticks:

```
$add = mysqli_query($connection, "ALTER TABLE `employee` add `PH_NO` INT(10)");
```

You should try using:

```
mysqli_errno($connection);  // Gets the error number.
mysqli_error($connection);  // Gets the error message.
```

To find out the error message. Also, it is wise to try the SQL in phpMyAdmin or something similar to check what's happening.

Comment: Awesome it worked. Thank you

Comment: @user3196569 For reference, please check this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png